# I can't get external JavaScript to work

Tags: javascript, html, external

We're (me and a few friends) working on a website, we want to display 4 images on a page and have 8 we want to cycle through. I think I've written an adequate script but none of my friends know JS and it's my first time using it. I'm not sure if I have errors in the JS or am having trouble linking to it from the HTML. The HTML document is named "index.html", in the directory there is a folder named "js" in  which we have all the JavaScript we are and will be using. We have a folder named "images" where we're holding all the images.

Here's the JS code:

```
var arregloImagen = new Array(
"../images/pic02.jpg",
"../images/pic03.jpg",
"../images/pic04.jpg",
"../images/pic05.jpg",
"../images/pic06.jpg",
"../images/pic07.jpg",
"../images/pic08.jpg",
"../images/pic09.jpg");
var contadorImagen =0;
function iniciaTiempo()  {
if(contadorImagen == arregloImagen.length){
    contadorImagen = 0;
    alert("Hello");
}
if(contadorImagen <= 4) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen];
    document.getElementById("img2").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen+1];
    document.getElementById("img3").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen+2];
    document.getElementById("img4").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen+3];
}
else{
    switch (contadorImagen) {
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("img1").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen-5];
            document.getElementById("img2").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen];
            document.getElementById("img3").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen+1];
            document.getElementById("img4").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen+2];
            break;

        case 6:
            document.getElementById("img1").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen-6];
            document.getElementById("img2").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen-5];
            document.getElementById("img3").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen];
            document.getElementById("img4").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen+1];
            break;

        case 7:
            document.getElementById("img1").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen-7];
            document.getElementById("img2").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen-6];
            document.getElementById("img3").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen-5];
            document.getElementById("img4").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen];
            break;
    }

}
contadorImagen++;


setTimeout("iniciaTiempo()", 1000);
}
```

And here I reference the JS from HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
<script>
    iniciaTiempo();
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: does both index.html and js   folder in the same directory ?

Comment: Why not output all your images to HTML and then toggle the display rather than changing src attributes all the time?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: in firefox add firebug, launch your page and check firebug error

Comment: It will not work because you are referencing the elements before they even exist!

Comment: @epascarello You're right! It started working as soon as I changed the method calls' position to a place where the ids and elements had been, erm, instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample - modify to fix your needs

```
<script>
var arregloImagen = new Array(
'../images/pic1.jpg',
"../images/pic2.jpg",
"../images/pic3.jpg",
"../images/pic4.jpg",
"../images/pic05.jpg",
"../images/pic06.jpg",
"../images/pic07.jpg",
"../images/pic08.jpg",
"../images/pic09.jpg");
var contadorImagen =2;

function iniciaTiempo()  {


if(contadorImagen <= 4) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = arregloImagen[contadorImagen];

    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.src=arregloImagen[contadorImagen];
    img.id="picture"+contadorImagen;
    var foo = document.getElementById("img"+contadorImagen);
    foo.appendChild(img);
}

}
</script>

<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="img1"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
<div id="img3"></div>
<div id="img4"></div>

<script>
    iniciaTiempo();
</script>

</body>
```